# "An error occured when executing the cache:clear --no-warmup" while installing symfony-cmf-standard

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-cmf

I was trying to install symfony-cmf-standard using:

```
composer.phar create-project symfony-cmf/standard-edition symfony-cmf-standard/ --stability=dev
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Could not open input file: app/console
Script sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

[RuntimeException]
An error occured when executing the cache:clear --no-warmup
```

I am running the command as an Administrator so it should not be a permission issue.

Comment: And what if you run in the command `php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup` with the same user?

Comment: Then it gives some other errors because of incomplete installation due to the above error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It gives error as when we use the command,

```
composer.phar create-project symfony-cmf/standard-edition symfony-cmf-standard/ --stability=dev
```

It creates symfony-cmf-standard folder as a project folder and starts installing dependencies but in between it tries to clear cache using

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

But as the current location is outside of the project folder it can not locate app/console so it fails.

Now if we change the directory to inside the project folder and clear cache manually by using command

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

It clears cache and then we need to again update dependencies using

```
php composer.phar update
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I've got an error cut also in the same case: "...PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DOMDocument' not found..."

Works after:

1. `install php-xml` (can be optionally compiled with this option I suppose)
2. set `date.timezone` in `/etc/php.ini`

Comment: Damn it. I forgot about that xml package. Thanks! After `sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml` the `composer install` worked absolutely perfect (I am working on a Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS with PHP-7.1 by the way, but should also work on other distributions as well).

Comment: brilliant, you saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

On my side with php7.0 I had to install :

- `php7.0-mbstring`
- `php7.0-xml`

Then it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the following bug in DoctrinePHPCRBundle: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrinePHPCRBundle/issues/17

To fix it, edit the file `vendor/doctrine/phpcr-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/PHPCRBundle/Resources/config/odm.xml` inside your `symfony-cmf-standard` folder and replace this line:

```
<parameter key="doctrine_phpcr.odm.metadata.driver_chain.class">Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\Mapping\Driver\DriverChain</parameter>
```

With this one:

```
<parameter key="doctrine_phpcr.odm.metadata.driver_chain.class">Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain</parameter>
```

Now copy `composer.phar` inside your `symfony-cmf-standard` folder and run with administrator privileges the command:

```
php composer.phar update
```

Comment: in vendor/doctrine/phpcr-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/PHPCRBundle/Resources/config/odm.xml file there is already, <parameter key="doctrine_phpcr.odm.metadata.driver_chain.class">Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain</parameter> still it gives same error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure these are installed:

- `php-mb` or `php54w-mbstring` or `php55w-mbstring`
- `php-xml` or `php54-xml` or `php55w-xml`

Answer (score 0):

After spending a couple hours on the issue, under FreeBSD you need to install port `textproc/php80-xmlreader` as well.