# Unable to install Sylius with Composer

Tags: symfony, sylius

With composer, i tried to install Sylius via **sylius/sylius** and **sylius/sylius-standard**.

Installations have both ended like this :

> *Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception*
>
> *[RuntimeException]
>
> An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'"* command.

It happens just after the parameters.ini initialization.

And after, the command line doesn't work (example : "app/console list" return nothing) although I'm in the project root directory.

Any idea, please ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you typed the error message in google? -> [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893082/an-error-occured-when-executing-the-cacheclear-no-warmup-while-installing-s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893082/an-error-occured-when-executing-the-cacheclear-no-warmup-while-installing-s)

Comment: Post the whole error message! Currently there are several dependency problems, like doctrine-bundle and so on.

Comment: For the error, this is all I have, sorry. np87, I have already seen this post, but it doesn't help :/

Comment: based on the time of the post, i can only guess that your on the latest version of doctrine.  there is a known issue currently with doctrine because they're adding a new feature and it's not quite working yet.  to get your stuff working right now change your doctrine bundle in your composer.json to :"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "v1.2.0",

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error ( I'm not sure if it's the same place where your getting it ) and developed a solution that seems to work.  Instead of running *app/console cache:clear* ( which I think gets run at the end of the composer install ), I run a bash script that opens the permissions before and after.

*sudo sh clearCache*

Contents of clearCache:

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod -R 777 app/cache/ app/logs/
su www-data -c "app/console cache:clear -e dev"
chmod -R 777 app/cache/ app/logs/
su www-data -c "app/console cache:clear -e prod"
chmod -R 777 app/cache/ app/logs/
```

I think I got this message during a composer install and was still able to continue via *cd Sylius* and *app/console sylius:install*.  Just run this before and after installing and updates.